# Custom scoring function random forest classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn to build a classifier which receives an imput X (vector of size 784 which is a 28x28 image representing a hand-written digit from 0 to 9) and predicts the number that is present on the image. Instead of using traditional accuracy, I would like the algorithm to penalize more the cases when digits from {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} are predicted to be from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

From what I understand it is not possible to change the loss function of a sklearn classifier so I have tried to change the scoring function used through GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters. Here is the custom scoring function I wrote :

```
def loss_fn(y_true,y_pred):
    loss_score = 0
    N = len(y_true)
    
    for i in range(N):
        if y_true[i] != y_pred[i]:
            if int(y_true[i]) >= 5 and int(y_pred[i]) < 5:
                loss_score += 2
            else:
                loss_score += 1
    return (1-1/N*loss_score)
```

It is a very naive function that accounts for 2 when a digit from {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} is predicted to be from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and 1 when the classifier makes a "normal" mistake. Here is my Random Forest classifier ?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier() 
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [600, 800, 1000, 1200],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}
custom_scorer = make_scorer(loss_fn)
clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=3, scoring = custom_scorer)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Returned hyperparameter: {}'.format(clf.best_params_))
print('Best classification accuracy in train is: {}'.format(clf.best_score_))
print('Classification accuracy on test is: {}'.format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Actually when I use the custom function and I try to classifiy my testing dataset I have one more digit from {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} are predicted to be from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} than what I get without any custom function. So, it doesn't work at all and I wonder why...

Is my custom scoring function too naive ? Am I making a mistake in the implementation ?
Is the lack of results due to the fact that changing the scoring function makes very little difference giving the loss function on which the algorithm is trained remains unchanged ?
Should I put more parameters in the param_grid ?